# How to make sure no telemetry is lost when querying Application Insights in a Visual Studio (local debug session of ASP.NET CORE)?

Tags: asp.net-core, debugging, local, azure-application-insights, sampling

I have an ASP .NET Core app with Application Insights added. I run it locally in debug mode, send in requests at a rate of 10 per second, then examine the telemetry. I see less than half of `request` telemetry events from ASP and less than half of `trace` events produced by `ILogger` inside my own code. I know about [adaptive sampling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/sampling#configuring-adaptive-sampling-for-aspnet-applications), but thought that `trace` events are excluded from it by default? (seeing how applications logs become traces in App Insights). I tried adding explicit config to make sure no telemetry  is lost, but so far it didn't work:

```cs
services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry((ApplicationInsightsServiceOptions opt) =>
{
opt.DeveloperMode = true;
opt.EnableAdaptiveSampling = false;
});
```

Can I somehow configure App Insights to gather 100% of telemetry in local debug?

*Update* after playing around with configuration and suggestions, I noticed that visual Studio debug session is limited to searching the last 250 events, and this is what deletes my telemetry.

[image: only the most recent 250 events are available for debug sessions]